# How to play Lottie animations in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, lottie

I have install pod files for Lottie and downloaded the hello.json file from lottiefiles.com

```
 LOTAnimationView *Hello_loader;
 Hello_loader = [LOTAnimationView animationNamed:@"hello"];
 [self.view addSubview:Hello_loader];
```

I had tried it in both `viewDidLoad()` and `viewDidAppear()` but still, it does not appear

I am new to this ios programming can anyone please help me to resolve this?. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Lottie 3, the `Animation` class is Codable and is not available directly in Objective-C. So I created a wrapper that will allow a similar api to be used in Objevtice-C (inspired by [this](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios/issues/845)) :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Lottie

@objc(AnimationView) class Z_OBJC_Wrapper_AnimationView: UIView {

    @objc var loop:Bool {
        get {
            return animationView.loopMode == .loop
        }
        set {
            animationView.loopMode = newValue ? .loop : .playOnce
        }
    }

    @objc var speed:CGFloat {
        get {
            return animationView.animationSpeed
        }
        set {
            animationView.animationSpeed = newValue
        }
    }

    @objc var progress:AnimationProgressTime {
        get {
            return animationView.currentProgress
        }
        set {
            animationView.currentProgress = newValue
        }
    }

    private let animationView: AnimationView

    @objc override init(frame: CGRect) {
        animationView = AnimationView()

        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        animationView = AnimationView()

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    // MARK: - Public Functions

    @objc func loadAnimation(name animationName:String) {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: animationName, ofType: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
                let animation:Animation = try JSONDecoder().decode(Animation.self, from: data)
                animationView.animation = animation
            } catch {
                assertionFailure("Could not read Lottie json file")
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     Plays the animation from its current state to the end.

     - Parameter completion: An optional completion closure to be called when the animation completes playing.
     */
    @objc func play(completion: LottieCompletionBlock? = nil) {
        animationView.play(completion: completion)
    }

    /**
     Pauses the animation in its current state.

     The completion closure will be called with `false`
     */
    public func pause() {
        animationView.pause()
    }

    /**
     Stops the animation and resets the view to its start frame.

     The completion closure will be called with `false`
     */
    @objc func stop() {
        animationView.stop()
    }

    // MARK: Play with progress

    /**
     Plays the animation from a progress (0-1) to a progress (0-1).

     - Parameter fromProgress: The start progress of the animation.
     - Parameter toProgress: The end progress of the animation.
     - Parameter loopMode: The loop behavior of the animation.
     - Parameter completion: An optional completion closure to be called when the animation stops.
     */
    @objc func play(fromProgress from: AnimationProgressTime,
                    toProgress to: AnimationProgressTime,
                    loop loopBool: Bool,
                    completion: LottieCompletionBlock? = nil) {
        let loopMode:LottieLoopMode = loopBool ? .loop : .playOnce
        animationView.play(fromProgress: from, toProgress: to, loopMode: loopMode, completion: completion)
    }

    /**
     Plays the animation from a progress (0-1) to a progress (0-1). The view's `loopMode` property will be used.

     - Parameter fromProgress: The start progress of the animation.
     - Parameter toProgress: The end progress of the animation.
     - Parameter completion: An optional completion closure to be called when the animation stops.
     */
    @objc func play(fromProgress from: AnimationProgressTime,
                    toProgress to: AnimationProgressTime,
                    completion: LottieCompletionBlock? = nil) {
        animationView.play(fromProgress: from, toProgress: to, loopMode: nil, completion: completion)
    }

    /**
     Plays the animation from the current progress to a progress (0-1).

     - Parameter toProgress: The end progress of the animation.
     - Parameter loopMode: The loop behavior of the animation.
     - Parameter completion: An optional completion closure to be called when the animation stops.
     */
    @objc func play(toProgress to: AnimationProgressTime,
                    loop loopBool: Bool,
                    completion: LottieCompletionBlock? = nil) {
        let loopMode:LottieLoopMode = loopBool ? .loop : .playOnce
        animationView.play(fromProgress: nil, toProgress: to, loopMode: loopMode, completion: completion)
    }

    /**
     Plays the animation from the current progress to a progress (0-1). The view's `loopMode` property will be used

     - Parameter toProgress: The end progress of the animation.
     - Parameter completion: An optional completion closure to be called when the animation stops.
     */
    @objc func play(toProgress to: AnimationProgressTime,
                    completion: LottieCompletionBlock? = nil) {
        animationView.play(fromProgress: nil, toProgress: to, loopMode: nil, completion: completion)
    }

    // MARK: Play with frame

    /**
     Plays the animation from a start frame to an end frame in the animation's framerate.

     - Parameter fromFrame: The start frame of the animation.
     - Parameter toFrame: The end frame of the animation.
     - Parameter loopMode: The loop behavior of the animation.
     - Parameter completion: An optional completion closure to be called when the animation stops.
     */
    @objc func play(fromFrame from: AnimationFrameTime,
                    toFrame to: AnimationFrameTime,
                    loop loopBool: Bool,
                    completion: LottieCompletionBlock? = nil) {
        let loopMode:LottieLoopMode = loopBool ? .loop : .playOnce
        animationView.play(fromFrame: from, toFrame: to, loopMode: loopMode, completion: completion)
    }

    /**
     Plays the animation from a start frame to an end frame in the animation's framerate. The view's `loopMode` property will be used.

     - Parameter fromFrame: The start frame of the animation.
     - Parameter toFrame: The end frame of the animation.
     - Parameter completion: An optional completion closure to be called when the animation stops.
     */
    @objc func play(fromFrame from: AnimationFrameTime,
                    toFrame to: AnimationFrameTime,
                    completion: LottieCompletionBlock? = nil) {
        animationView.play(fromFrame: from, toFrame: to, loopMode: nil, completion: completion)

    }

    /**
     Plays the animation from the current frame to an end frame in the animation's framerate.

     - Parameter toFrame: The end frame of the animation.
     - Parameter loopMode: The loop behavior of the animation.
     - Parameter completion: An optional completion closure to be called when the animation stops.
     */
    @objc func play(toFrame to: AnimationFrameTime,
                    loop loopBool: Bool,
                    completion: LottieCompletionBlock? = nil) {
        let loopMode:LottieLoopMode = loopBool ? .loop : .playOnce
        animationView.play(fromFrame: nil, toFrame: to, loopMode: loopMode, completion: completion)

    }

    /**
     Plays the animation from the current frame to an end frame in the animation's framerate. The view's `loopMode` property will be used.

     - Parameter toFrame: The end frame of the animation.
     - Parameter completion: An optional completion closure to be called when the animation stops.
     */
    @objc func play(toFrame to: AnimationFrameTime,
                    completion: LottieCompletionBlock? = nil) {
        animationView.play(fromFrame: nil, toFrame: to, loopMode: nil, completion: completion)
    }

    // MARK: Play with marker

    /**
     Plays the animation from a named marker to another marker.

     Markers are point in time that are encoded into the Animation data and assigned
     a name.

     NOTE: If markers are not found the play command will exit.

     - Parameter fromMarker: The start marker for the animation playback.
     - Parameter toMarker: The end marker for the animation playback.
     - Parameter loopMode: The loop behavior of the animation.
     - Parameter completion: An optional completion closure to be called when the animation stops.
     */
    @objc func play(fromMarker from: String,
                    toMarker to: String,
                    loop loopBool: Bool,
                    completion: LottieCompletionBlock? = nil) {
        let loopMode:LottieLoopMode = loopBool ? .loop : .playOnce
        animationView.play(fromMarker: from, toMarker: to, loopMode: loopMode, completion: completion)
    }

    /**
     Plays the animation from a named marker to another marker. The view's `loopMode` property will be used.

     Markers are point in time that are encoded into the Animation data and assigned
     a name.

     NOTE: If markers are not found the play command will exit.

     - Parameter fromMarker: The start marker for the animation playback.
     - Parameter toMarker: The end marker for the animation playback.
     - Parameter completion: An optional completion closure to be called when the animation stops.
     */
    @objc func play(fromMarker from: String,
                    toMarker to: String,
                    completion: LottieCompletionBlock? = nil) {
        animationView.play(fromMarker: from, toMarker: to, loopMode: nil, completion: completion)
    }

    /**
     Plays the animation the current progress to a named marker.

     Markers are point in time that are encoded into the Animation data and assigned
     a name.

     NOTE: If markers are not found the play command will exit.

     - Parameter toMarker: The end marker for the animation playback.
     - Parameter loopMode: The loop behavior of the animation.
     - Parameter completion: An optional completion closure to be called when the animation stops.
     */
    @objc func play(toMarker to: String,
                    loop loopBool: Bool,
                    completion: LottieCompletionBlock? = nil) {
        let loopMode:LottieLoopMode = loopBool ? .loop : .playOnce
        animationView.play(fromMarker: nil, toMarker: to, loopMode: loopMode, completion: completion)
    }

    /**
     Plays the animation from the current progress to named marker. The view's `loopMode` property will be used.

     Markers are point in time that are encoded into the Animation data and assigned
     a name.

     NOTE: If markers are not found the play command will exit.

     - Parameter toMarker: The end marker for the animation playback.
     - Parameter completion: An optional completion closure to be called when the animation stops.
     */
    @objc func play(toMarker to: String,
                    completion: LottieCompletionBlock? = nil) {
        animationView.play(fromMarker: nil, toMarker: to, loopMode: nil, completion: completion)
    }

    // MARK: - Private

    private func commonInit() {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        setUpViews()
    }

    private func setUpViews() {
        animationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(animationView)
        animationView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        animationView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        animationView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        animationView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Usage in Objective-C :

```
AnimationView *loader = [[AnimationView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];
[loader loadAnimationWithName:@"loader"];
[loader playWithCompletion:nil];

[self addSubview:loader];
```

Comment: Why is the loader added as a subview after it has been added? That seems kind of strange to me.

Comment: Any idea why the AnimationView wouldn't be respecting the frame? I'm drawing the same frame you are above, but the animation is displaying 500x500.

Answer (score 1):

The last `Lottie` version that supports `Objective C` is 2.5.3. Most of the latest public lottie files are compiled for version 3+. However one might need  an objective-C only solution.

Add the Lottie with mentioning the version in the pod file.

```
pod 'lottie-ios', '2.5.3'
```

I like to keep the loading and playing code in separate methods.

In the .h file

```
#import <Lottie/Lottie.h>
...
LOTAnimationView * animation;
```

In the .m file

```
-(void) loadAnimation {
    NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"public-animation" ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData
                                                            options:kNilOptions
                                                              error:nil];

    animation = [LOTAnimationView animationFromJSON:jsonDict];

}

// animation is an instance of LOTAnimationView which is a subclass of UIView 
// at a base level. Hence it accepts all the related 
// properties (e.g setFrame, setCenter etc).

-(void) playAnimation {

    if ([animation isAnimationPlaying]) {
        [animation stop];
    }        
    [self.view addSubview:animation];  
    [animation play];    
}
```

Now call the animation as you desire.

```
[self playAnimation];
```

Glad to know that the problem is already solved, I thought it would be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 LOTAnimationView *hello_loader = [LOTAnimationView animationNamed:@"hello"];
 [self.view addSubview:hello_loader];
 [hello_loader play];
```

Comment: Still not working... it's viewing the blank page @IOS

Comment: try this [self. Hello_loader play];

Comment: the above code throws an error  [Property 'hello_loader' not found on object of type 'ViewController *']

Comment: check edited answer bcs you already declare Hello_loader object

Comment: it is working...but no as my wish it just showing the line but i wanted to show is linked above can you please help me

Comment: I wanted to load like hello in the above description...but its just showing the lines....can you please help me in this @IOS

Comment: @RKios ok wait  i will create demo

Comment: Did you Created it

Comment: @RKios whats the problem?

Comment: NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ShopCollectionObject sizeWithAttributes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000026f200'

Comment: Got this error and app crashes in collection view controller

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153018/my-application-crashes-with-this-error-nsinvalidargumentexception-reason

Comment: please check this link @IOS

Comment: hey need a help @IOS

Comment: please  [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185846/how-can-i-parse-xml-data-using-afnetworking-3-0).   @IOS

Comment: above code is not working. Can you please share the objective-c code snippet?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -2):

**Swift 5 (with latest version of lottie)**

```
    let animationView = AnimationView(name: "Bubbles") //Replace "Bubbles" with your animation file name.
    animationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150)
    animationView.center = self.view.center
    animationView.loopMode = .loop
    animationView.backgroundBehavior = .pauseAndRestore //to pause in background and restart when it reach foreground
    self.view.addSubview(animationView)
    animationView.play()
```

[Check output on this link](https://appetize.io/app/crm0z5uvyf0krk0j4y1c25u1aw)

Comment: Appreciated but the question specified objective-c.

Comment: @Neo You can give answer in Objective-c.

Comment: The answer is above :)

Comment: Now a days only few developers are there who still work in Objecive-c like you, other are moved to latest trend, i don't think that my answer is wrong

Comment: It's not wrong. Just doing the "civic duty" of StackOverflow. Also I only use Objective-C in legacy projects. I only write Swift. But no need to drag this any further.