# My application crashes with this error - 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uicollectionview

I have created a program to retrieve JSON file and it achieved it

```
NSString *FilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Message" ofType:@"json"];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:FilePath];
NSError *error;
if(error){
    NSLog(@"Error and CAn't retrive data: %@", error.localizedDescription);

}else{
    NSDictionary * jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Your Json Dictionary values are %@", jsonDict);
    for(NSDictionary *valuesDictionary in jsonDict){
ShopCollectionObject *shopObject = [[ShopCollectionObject alloc]initWithID:[[valuesDictionary objectForKey:@"message_id"]integerValue] Name:[valuesDictionary objectForKey:@"product"] TimeAsPrice:[[valuesDictionary objectForKey:@"message_time"]integerValue] Avathar:[valuesDictionary objectForKey:@"item_image"] user:[valuesDictionary objectForKey:@"user_image"] Name_User:[valuesDictionary objectForKey:@"user_name"] LocationOfUser:[valuesDictionary objectForKey:@"locate_user"]];
```

But My app crashes here with the above error

```
  [self.objectForArray addObject:shopObject];
    }

}
```

Updated my shop collection code below

Shopcollection object.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ShopCollectionObject : NSObject

-(instancetype) initWithID: (int)msgID Name:(NSString *)Profile_name TimeAsPrice:(int) GivenTimeAsPrice Avathar:(NSString *) PhotoOfAvathar user:(NSString *)UserAvathar Name_User: (NSString *) UserNames LocationOfUser:(NSString *) USerLocationGiven;
@property (nonatomic) int msgID;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString* Name;
@property (nonatomic) int TimeAsPrice;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* Avathar;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* user;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* Name_User;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString* LocationOfUser;
@end
```

Shopcollectionobject.m

```
#import "ShopCollectionObject.h"

@implementation ShopCollectionObject

-(instancetype)initWithID:(int)msgID Name:(NSString *)Profile_name TimeAsPrice:(int)GivenTimeAsPrice Avathar:(NSString *)PhotoOfAvathar user:(NSString *)UserAvathar Name_User:(NSString *)UserNames LocationOfUser:(NSString *)USerLocationGiven{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
     self.msgID = msgID;
    self.Name = Profile_name;
    self.TimeAsPrice = GivenTimeAsPrice;
    self.Avathar = PhotoOfAvathar;
    self.user = UserAvathar;
    self.Name_User = UserNames;
    self.LocationOfUser = USerLocationGiven;
}
return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: pls check json data i think some data converting issue

Comment: chech you jsonDict does it has all dics of convertable to ShopCollectionObject class.

Comment: I checked my JSON data it working fine...

Comment: pls add your json file

Comment: Updated my JSON above

Comment: add your ShopCollectionObject class code

Comment: give me time i am checking your code

Comment: Please show FULL Error message. You didn't give the meaningful one. Also name your vars starting with an lowercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ShopCollectionObject.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ShopCollectionObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) int message_id;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *Name;
@property (nonatomic) int TimeAsPrice;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *Avathar;//user,Name_User,LocationOfUser,message_id
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *user;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *Name_User;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *LocationOfUser;
-(instancetype) initWithID: (int)msgID Name:(NSString *)Profile_name TimeAsPrice:(int) GivenTimeAsPrice Avathar:(NSString *) PhotoOfAvathar user:(NSString *)UserAvathar Name_User: (NSString *) UserNames LocationOfUser:(NSString *) USerLocationGiven;
@property (nonatomic) int msgID;
@end
```

ShopCollectionObject.m

```
#import "ShopCollectionObject.h"

@implementation ShopCollectionObject
-(instancetype)initWithID:(int)msgID Name:(NSString *)Profile_name TimeAsPrice:(int)GivenTimeAsPrice Avathar:(NSString *)PhotoOfAvathar user:(NSString *)UserAvathar Name_User:(NSString *)UserNames LocationOfUser:(NSString *)USerLocationGiven{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        self.msgID = msgID;
        self.Name = Profile_name;
        self.TimeAsPrice = GivenTimeAsPrice;
        self.Avathar = PhotoOfAvathar;
        self.user = UserAvathar;
        self.Name_User = UserNames;
        self.LocationOfUser = USerLocationGiven;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ShopCollectionObject.h"
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *objectForArray;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    objectForArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString *FilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Message" ofType:@"json"];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:FilePath];
    NSError *error;
    if(error){
        NSLog(@"Error and CAn't retrive data: %@", error.localizedDescription);

    }else{
        NSDictionary * jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        for(NSDictionary *valuesDictionary in jsonDict){
            ShopCollectionObject *shopObject = [[ShopCollectionObject alloc]initWithID:[[valuesDictionary objectForKey:@"message_id"]intValue] Name:[valuesDictionary objectForKey:@"product"] TimeAsPrice:[[valuesDictionary objectForKey:@"message_time"]intValue] Avathar:[valuesDictionary objectForKey:@"item_image"] user:[valuesDictionary objectForKey:@"user_image"] Name_User:[valuesDictionary objectForKey:@"user_name"] LocationOfUser:[valuesDictionary objectForKey:@"locate_user"]];
            [objectForArray addObject:shopObject];
        }
        NSLog(@"%@",objectForArray);
        ShopCollectionObject *data = objectForArray[0];
        NSLog(@"%@",data.Name);
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

pls check this code

Comment: Worked Thank You

Comment: Don't just post code as an answer, please indicate what is different.

Answer (score 1):

You likely aren't initializing your objectForArray.  So when you try to call addObject, it's calling it on a null object.