# How can I parse XML data using AFNetworking 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing, afnetworking-3

I am doing a simple project to display the weather report using this [a link](https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php?wsdl) 
and I implemented the following code to get the result...

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager GET:@"https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php?wsdl" parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * task, id responseObject) {
    NSData * data = (NSData *)responseObject;
    NSLog(@"Response String: %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]]);
 }failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *  operation, NSError *  error) {
    NSLog(@"Error the result is unfound in the database %@", error);

}];
```

In the above code, I finally retrieved XML but I don't know how to parse it and make it display in table view... I am new to ios developing can anyone please help me what to do to get data and display it in tableview..

Comment: check this link http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/

Comment: Got error in that code @IOS

Comment: @IOS Can i get a tutorial for stripe payment in objective c

Comment: sorry i have no demo pls check https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios

Comment: @IOS How can I Make view popups when I clicked my button for loading

Answer (score 0):

every xml files like property list can be cast as NSDictionary , i am swift developer but , if you have data in xml its possible to cast it to NSDictionary

in Swift 4 :

```
do {
   if let plist = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: plistData, 
    format: nil)
        as? NSDictionary  {
            // Successfully read  list.
            print(plist)

        } else {
            print("not a dictionary")
        }
} catch let error {
    print("not a plist:", error.localizedDescription)
}
```

In Objective-C :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPlist.plist"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPlist" ofType:@"plist"];
}

NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

> in this case you can pass your data instead of Plist

now you can cache data into your models and show them in your UITableView

good luck ;)